# Showing and hiding a view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Long time listener, first time caller..

I am attempting to add a banner to my app that will display when there is no network connection.  My app uses about 9 view controllers, so I thought an extension to the UIViewcontroller would be the smart place to start.  I have some logic that checks the health of the network, then based on a fail, it drives a NotificationCenter.post to display a viewController over the current display.  This code resides in the UIViewController extension and is used to show the screen - it seems to function:

```
 func showNoNetworkBanner()
    {
        if let theMask = parent?.view.viewWithTag(666) {
            return  // already setted..
        } else {
            let maskView = UIView()
            maskView.tag = 666
            maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_NotNetworkWarning") as! vc_NotNetworkWarning
            maskView.addSubview(vc.view)
            parent?.view.addSubview(maskView)

        }
    }
```

On the other side, when the view controller appears there is some code that runs within the view controller to see if the health is okay.  If the health is okay, it will make the view controller go away.  Within the view controller I have tried just about everything.  When I use this code, the view controller never goes away.

```
  let vc = parent?.view.viewWithTag(666)
    vc?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Another variation I have tried is using the .removeFrom ParentViewController() and the ViewController does go away, but then my code to call it does not work as the viewWithTag(666) always returns true.

```
self.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Can someone help me out?  Is there a better way to display a single 'banner' over any view controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening.

Based on your question i assume you're networkconnection check works as it should. I would display the banner in the following way:

1. create the banner using a new .swift file containing the following code:

   ```
   class BannerViewLauncher: NSObject  {

       var viewController: UIViewController?

       lazy var bannerView : UIView = {
           let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
           view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
           return view
       }()

       //create more UIelements if you want to design the banner further. don't forget to add them as subviews to the bannerView and give them constraints.

       func showNoNetworkBanner() {

           if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

               window.addSubview(bannerView)

               //define your desired size here (y position is out of view so it is off view by default, the y position will be changed when you call the showNoNetworkBanner() method.
               bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: window.frame.width, height: 100)
               //change withDuration if you want it to display slower or faster, just change all of them to the same for it so look good
               UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

                   self.bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: window.frame.width, height: 100)

               }, completion: nil)

           }
       }

       func hideNoNetworkBanner() {
           if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

                   self.bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: window.frame.width, height: 100)

           }, completion: nil)
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. In the ViewController you would like to display this (one or more) subclass the `BannerViewLauncher` and call the method as described when your NoNetwork observer methods trigger.

   ```
   lazy var bannerViewLauncher : BannerViewLauncher = {
       let launcher = BannerViewLauncher()
       launcher.viewController = self
       return launcher
   }()

   //call the following when you want the banner to display
   bannerViewLauncher.showNoNetworkBanner()

   //call this when you want to hide the banner
   bannerViewLauncher.hideNoNetworkBanner()
   ```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thank you for your quick and thorough reply.  I bolted it into my code and now my problem is gone.  Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful! Good to hear.